# Using Google Apps Scripts offline

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, offline

Is it possible to use Google Apps Scripts offline? I have a Google Spreadsheet with scripts to keep things updated as I add data. I do not need to edit the scripts, but I need to be able to run them for my spreadsheet to make sense.

If not, are there any speadsheets applications, that would allow for easy porting of scripts?

Comment: What does it mean to run a script offline on data that is stored in the cloud (that is, online)?

Comment: I'm using Google Docs offline and I'm hoping to get the scripts to run offline as well. I am only using GAS to edit the spreadsheet itself using SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert this google script to work offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094232/how-do-i-convert-this-google-script-to-work-offline)

Answer (score 3):

You can not because Google Apps Script run in Cloud. But you can use [New Google Sheets](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/new-google-sheets-faster-more-powerful.html) offline.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The new Google Sheets work offline [(if you've got offline access enabled)](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012) but I've just a little experiment and the script I've attached to the sheet doesn't run (I set it up to trigger on a cell edit and display a msgBox).

Answer (score -1):

With triggers, your sheet can continue to be edited while you are offline. Once you are back you should receive the changes.