# Is it possible to export a spreadsheet and all its projects (scripts) and use it offline?

Tags: google-apps-script

For one of the projects I've been working on (large spreadsheet, two worksheets, three projects/scripts) I actually have to save this project somewhere offline, in an *extremely* standard format (there are heavy regulations for submission of this project), so even though Google is pretty widely used, it might not be acceptable to leave this project online available to anyone with a link. Can I somehow get this to work exported as an Excel spreadsheet that still works with the scripts I've added to it?

I'm sort of at a loss as to what to do with it now. I might try exporting this as an Excel spreadsheet with a bunch of missing functionality and just tell them that for full functionality they'll have to use Google Drive.

Any suggestions, or is there really no way to get proper functionality of Google Apps Scripts offline?

Comment: I don't think there is a way.
Google spreadsheet => Google App Script. 
Microsoft Excel => Microsoft VBA.

Comment: That's what I was a afraid of, @Adelin. Oh well, hopefully I'll think of some workaround.

Comment: But can't you limit it per user? I was in your exact situation but what I did was either create a database with usernames and passwords, or get user logged in with `Session.getActiveUser()`. That why you can control who sees/uses the project and who don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is possible to export a spreadsheet and the Google Apps Script project bounded to it  as separate files but it's not possible to use them together offline as Google Apps Script runs on the server side and it's neither possible to automatically convert a Google spreadsheet with a Google Apps Script to a Excel macro file (including a Visual Basic for Applications project).

## References

### Stack Overflow related questions

- [Using Google Apps Scripts offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366836/using-google-apps-scripts-offline)

### Google Developers Blog

- [Advanced Development Process with Apps Script](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/12/advanced-development-process-with-apps.html)
- [Total Eclipse of the Apps Script](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/10/total-eclipse-of-apps-script.html)