# How do I convert this google script to work offline?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, offline, chromebook

I am trying to automate data entry while roaming offline using my Chromebook.

I know that google drive is enabled offline and a standalone script in GAS should in theory do the trick but im not sure how to put the pieces together. So far I have the below code which works perfectly online (gets stuck in "running" offline) and I've got the GAS app installed. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
// Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
ui.createMenu('Invoice/Receipt System')
// creates a menu item "Submit Order"
.addItem('Record Invoice', 'menuItem1')
.addToUi();
}


function menuItem1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var is = ss.getSpreadsheetByName("Template_Invoice");

  var lastID = is.getRange("j6");
  var nextID = is.getRange("j7");

  var lastIDValue = lastID.getValue();

var source = ss.getSpreadsheetByName("Key_Invoice"); 
// sets the 'Key_DailyInput' Sheet as source
var target = ss.geSpreadsheetByName("DataBase_Invoice");
// sets 'Key_DailyInput' sheet as the target for copying data to.
var sourceData = source.getSheetValues(5,1,source.getLastRow(),15);
// sets range to gather source 'Key_DailyInput' data by finding last row, and Line 5 to Column 15
target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1, 1, sourceData.length,15).setValues(sourceData);
// finds last row of target 'Orders' and writes to +1 row past last row up to column 15 using setValues of sourceData

// Following simply clears DailyInput so new data can be entered
is.getRange('C5:c8').clearContent();
is.getRange('G7:G8').clearContent();
is.getRange('B12:h28').clearContent();
is.getRange('b31:b34').clearContent();


// increases value by +1 so next Sales Order ID is incremented by 1
var cell = is.getRange("j6");
var cellValue = cell.getValue();
cell.setValue(cellValue + 1);

nextID.setValue(lastIDValue + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Google Apps Script can't be ran offline because they run on the server-side.

## Explanation

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

> Google Apps Script is a scripting language based on JavaScript that
> lets you do new and cool things with Google Apps like Docs, Sheets,
> and Forms. There's nothing to install — we give you a code editor
> right in your browser, and your scripts run on Google's servers.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, would this still be the case if I created a webapp with the script?

Comment: @Tiana, yes, it is the same case.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in other responses, the answer appears to be 'No'. However, while researching I did find the Command Line Interface for Apps Script (clasp) to manage and edit your projects offline. I'll post it here hoping it will be helpful to Apps Script developers.

```
CLASP Features
Develop Locally. clasp lets you write code on your own computer and upload it to Apps Script via command line when you're done. You can also download existing Apps Script projects and then edit them locally. Once the code is local, you can use your favorite development tools like git to work on Apps Script projects.
*  Manage Deployment Versions. 
*  Create, update, and view multiple deployments of your project.
*  Structure Code. clasp automatically converts your flat project on script.google.com into folders.
```

You can find more information on clasp at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp. However, you'll also need to activate the Linux(beta) on your Chromebook utilizing [these instructions](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en).